# Metrics from Google Analytics Custom Report and Google Analytics Python API don't match. There is difference in the metric's value

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am unable to get the exact value from a Google Analytics Custom Report through Python API. Users metric is 1013,523 in the GA Custom report by Python API returns 102,4972.

I believe I am not using REGEX correctly in the first filter. Can someone please tell me if I have done it incorrectly?

```
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=('https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest'))
response = service.reports().batchGet(
    body={
        'reportRequests': [
            {
                'viewId': 'XXX', 
                'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '2022-12-04', 'endDate': '2022-12-10'}],
                'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:users'}], 
                'dimensions': [{"name": "ga:week"},{"name":"ga:country"}], 
                "dimensionFilterClauses": [
                                        {    
                                            "filters": [
                                            {
                                              "dimensionName": "ga:pagePath",
                                              "operator": "REGEXP",
                                              "expressions": ["www\.test\.com|my\.test.com\/upgrade"]
                                            }
                                          ]
                                        },
                                        {
                                          "filters": [
                                            {
                                              "dimensionName": "ga:country",
                                              "operator": "EXACT",
                                              "expressions": ["United States"]
                                            }
                                          ]
                                        },
                                        {    
                                            "filters": [
                                            {
                                              "dimensionName": "ga:pagePath",
                                              "not":1,
                                              "operator": "REGEXP",
                                              "expressions": ["blog"]
                                            }
                                          ]
                                        }
                                      ]
        }]
}
).execute()
```

This is how the filter is set on Google Analytics Custom Reports -
[image]

This is how the report looks like in Google Analytics -
[image]

Comment: can i see a picture of the report you are trying to recreate,  remember all the dimensions and metrics must be the same for the report to match.

Comment: Sure, I have added a picture of that